# Perl how to join all threads

Tags: perl

My code is like below:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue;

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
my @threads = ();
my $run :shared = 1;

$SIG{'TERM'} = sub {
    $run = 0;
    $q->enqueue('exit');
    foreach(@threads){
        $_->join();
    }
};

push @threads, threads->create(proc1);
push @threads, threads->create(proc2);

sub proc1 {

    while($p = $q->dequeue()){
        if($p eq 'exit'){
            last;
        }
        .....
    }
    $q->end();
    threads->exit();
}

sub proc2 {
    while($run){
       .....
    }
}
```

On TERM signal im trying to wait till all threads are ended. However, whenever I pass TERM signal my program gets terminated with an error

```
Segmentation fault
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: What version of Perl are you using?

Comment: I am using perl 5.10.1

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `threads->create(proc1)` even works (and that would only be because you didn't use `use strict;` as you should), then your program exits immediately after creating the threads. You need to have your main thread wait for the children threads to finish.

Fixing that problem (and applying some simplifications) results in the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Thread::Queue 3.01 qw( );

my $q = Thread::Queue->new();
my $run :shared = 1;

$SIG{TERM} = sub {
    print("Received SIGTERM. Shutting down...\n");
    $run = 0;
    $q->end();
};

print("$$\n");

threads->create(\&proc1);
threads->create(\&proc2);

$_->join() for threads->list();

sub proc1 {
    while(my $p = $q->dequeue()) {
        sleep 1;  # Placeholder
    }
}

sub proc2 {
    while($run){
        sleep 1;  # Placeholder
    }
}
```

I don't get a seg fault, but the program doesn't exit either. The signal handler is simply not called. It's because Perl is waiting for `join` to return before calling the signal handler. You can solve that by polling the list of joinable threads. In other words, replace

```
$_->join() for threads->list();
```

with

```
my $running_threads = 2;
while ($running_threads) {
    for my $thread (threads->list(threads::joinable)) {
        $thread->join();
        $running_threads--;
    }

    sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last choose snippet a little bit. I think the for loop will "get" all the threads without a while

Comment: @Sobrique, like I said in more detail in the answer, is to allow the signal to be handled

Comment: Would offer that instead of using a shared `$run` you can refer to the queue state - reading `$q->pending` will let you detect if it has ended (because `pending` returns `undef`).

Comment: @Sobrique, Not a bad idea, except those workers seem to be unrelated, so that would introduce unnecessary coupling.

Comment: @user3360140, I seem to have deleted part of my answer by accident before even posting it. Updated my answer to reinclude the reason changes were needed.

Comment: @ikegami thanks a lot for your response. Basically i was not sure what exactly was causing my issue. Now I am and I also come up with a code by which you can reproduce the error I got. I opened up a new thread please check it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279157/perl-seg-fault-while-joining-threads