# Perl seg fault while joining threads

Tags: multithreading, perl

I have a code similar to the below. I have one main script which is calling another module named initial.pm. initial.pm opens up connection with an AMQP server (In my case RabbitMQ)and using  Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ library for establishing the connection. Everything works fine except when I try to join my threads I get **segmentation fault**.

I think the Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ is not thread safe. But this is only being used by the main thread. Im pretty sure you can reproduce the error if you just copy and past the codes below.

How do I fix it ?

**main.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Cwd qw/realpath/;
use File::Basename qw/dirname/;
use lib 'lib';
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use initial;

my @threads = ();
my $run :shared = 1;

my $init = load initial($name);

$SIG{'TERM'} = sub {
    $run = 0;
};

threads->create(\&proc1);
threads->create(\&proc2);


while($run){
    sleep(1);
    print "I am main thread\n";
}

$_->join() for threads->list();

sub proc1 {
    while($run){
        sleep(1);
        print "I am child thread 1 \n"
    }
}

sub proc2 {
    while($run){
       sleep(1);
       print "I am child thread 2 \n";
    }
}
```

**lib/initial.pm**

```
package initial;

use Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ;
use Cwd qw/realpath/;
use File::Basename qw/dirname/;

my $mq;
my $stop = 0;

sub load {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    connectq();
    bless $self,$class;
    return $self;
}

sub connectq {
    $mq = Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ->new();
    my ($host,$port,$user,$pass) = ('localhost','5672','guest','guest');
    $mq->connect($host, {
        user => $user,
        password => $pass,
        port => $port,
        timeout => 10,
    });

    $mq->channel_open(1);
    $mq->consume(1, 'logger');
}

1;
```

Comment: Perl threads are heavy. Each thread will have its own copy of your `$init` variable, and the thread safety of your `initial` class will be relevant. Do you have any better luck putting your `$init` assignment after the creation of your two threads?

Comment: Why did you move the `join` back into the signal handler. That makes no sense.

Comment: The obvious guess is that Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ isn't threadsafe

Comment: I updated the code please check now. Having same issue. Yes Net::AMQP::RabbitMQ is not thread safe. is there any fix?

Comment: @mob I dont see the error If I call initial class after creating the threads. But this is just part of a bigger code and calling the class every time after creating a thread is not the solution in my case. Is there a way to tell perl not to copy my $init variable ?

Comment: I dunno. What if you make `$init` a shared variable?

Comment: If you are not using a thread safe library, you can sometimes get away with it by keeping it within just one thread. E.g. Ensure "use"/"require"/"import" happen after the threads are instantiated.

Comment: Alternatively use forking instead of threading.

Comment: How about locking? can I lock the variable which is not thread safe? Can that somehow solve my issue?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your problem directly, because I don't have the library installed.

One way of 'faking' thread safety in a not-thread-safe module is to rescope your 'use' to only the bit where you'll be using it.

You see, when you start a thread, it copies the program state - loaded libraries and everything.

If your run (something like):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

sub thread1 {
    print threads->self->tid.": Includes:", Dumper \%INC,"\n";
}


#main;

print "Main includes:", Dumper \%INC,"\n";
threads -> create ( \&thread1 );
```

You'll see `XML::Twig` is loaded in both. If the process of 'loading' the module causes some state changes (and it can) then you immediately have a potential thread-safety issue.

However if you instead do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use threads;
use Data::Dumper;

sub thread1 {
    require XML::Twig;
    XML::Twig -> import;
    print threads->self->tid.": Includes:", Dumper (\%INC),"\n";
}


#main;

print "Main includes:", Dumper (\%INC),"\n";
threads -> create ( \&thread1 );
foreach my $thr ( threads -> list ) { 
   $thr -> join;
}
```

You *effectively* cause the module to be dynamically loaded within the thread - the module is only present in one 'code instance' so you are much less likely to be tripped up by 'thread safety' issues.

Alternatively - `fork`ing instead of `thread`ing ... might be an alternative. This has slightly different 'safety' problems.

But there really is no way to avoid this. Even with shared variables, the core problem is - when you thread, bits of code happen in a different order. There's all sorts of fruity things that can happen as a result. A shared var is one way of ensuring it's the *same* variable being checked each time - e.g. share `$init`, but that may well make things worse, because you're then potentially trampling over the same instance/sockets with different threads.

You can, however, reduce the 'thread safety' problem to a limited scope, and use e.g. `Thread::Queue` to pass messages to/from your 'module user' thread.

Comment: can locking be a solution?

Comment: In theory, yes. In practice, you would have to dismantle the module and find the source of the problems, and place a guard around it. There may be multiple.  Not impossible, but not easy either.